# web scraping in python - retrieving text from either of two nested levels

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup in python to retrieve information from a website like  [this one from indeed](https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20scientist%20$20,000&l=New%20York&start=10/)

I'm trying to retrieve information on the "location" of job postings, which can be found at one of two levels of nested html.

Sometimes, the text I want is within tags with (name="span", attrs={"class":"location"})

Othertimes, the text I want is in another tag (name='span', attrs={"itemprop":"addressLocality"}) that's nested within the first tag above.

I'm trying to write a loop that will check to see if the location text I want (e.g., "New York, NY") is within the first tag, and, if not, to retrieve it from the second tag.

Currently, the best I can come up with is:

```
for item in soup.find_all(name='span', attrs={"class":"location"}):
    print(item.renderContents())
```

However, this gives me the undesirable output of:

```
New York, NY 10001
New York, NY
New York, NY 10154
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY 10016 <span style="font-size: smaller">(Gramercy area)</span></span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Manhattan, NY</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY 10016 <span style="font-size: smaller">(Gramercy area)</span></span>
New York, NY
New York, NY 10154
```

I would ideally like to have all of the normally appearing text stay how it is, and strip out the "span itemprop="addressLocality"", etc. from the other results. I've tried writing a few try/except statements to accomplish this, but haven't gotten anything to work.

I could save the entire contents to a list and write separate code to strip out this additional burdensome text, but I would appreciate a more elegant way of accomplishing this within the initial retrieval.

Could anyone help me with this?  Thank you for your consideration!

Answer (score 1):

If you can contrive to get just the `span` with `class=location` (and assuming that these are exactly the items you want in the document) then, whether nested or not, they contain the same `text`.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<span class="location" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Postaladdress"><span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY</span></span>', 'lxml')
>>> soup.text
'New York, NY'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<span class=location>New York, NY</span>', 'lxml')
>>> soup.text
'New York, NY'
```

EDIT: Getting the whole list.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> URL = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20scientist%20$20,000&l=New%20York&start=10/'
>>> page = requests.get(URL).text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'location'})
>>> for span in spans:
...     span.text
...     
'New York, NY 10154'
'New York, NY 10003'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY 10018 (Clinton area)'
'New York, NY'
'New York, NY 10001'
```

Comment: Hi, this did help a bit, but I was hoping to produce a full list of locations like in my original output above, except without any of the added html tags (e.g., <span itemprop="addressLocality">).  Would you happen to know more about this?

Comment: Wow, thank you - this works!  It seems easy, but I'm still a little confused.  Does the "for span in spans: span.text" essentially print whatever text appears anywhere in the top-level span tag or any subsequently nested tags?  Thank you again, this is awesome.

Comment: The `for span in spans` simply iterates through the collection that `soup` found in the preceding line. Nothing special about that. The `.text` in the next line picks up *all* of the text in `span` (which is just one item in a list of items and could have had *any* name) so that it can be processed. In your case sometimes `span` contains an unadorned `<span>` and sometime a nested `<span>`. Doesn't matter, you still get the enclosed text. In fact, if `span` contained something like a `<div>` you'd still get whatever text was in there. You might even get a few text items together.

Comment: Excellent - thank you again so much for the helpful explanation =)